# Is it possible to embed external application or UIView or UIViewControler in application under ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, embed, external

Things are this way, I plan to write an application(or plugin or something like this, I am not clear about this now because I don't know how to realize this requirement), and I'd like to other developers can embed view of my application into their application. It is designed to reuse my view for other developers.

It's a little like XEmbed protocol, but it is different

It is possible under ios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. What you can do is register a URL scheme so other application can call yours by opening yourapp://url?param=value. You can then open a specific view (depending on the passed URL) and return back to the invoker app when done.

Edit: or you can make a library that other apps would link with and call some method(s) that would return a view.

Comment: Thank you, sir. I think I have to create a static library.